# When a plugin gets updated from the repo, does the "activation" hook fire again?

Tags: hooks, activation, plugin-repository

When you activate a plugin, it goes through the whole activate .. bounce to the next page thing. Does the plugin fire that hook when it is updated, or only during the initial installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activation hook is only fired when the plugin is first activated, not when it's updated.